# Delete a relationship in neo4j 1.6 using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I think it is a simple question but I am not able to find the answer.
I have tried various ways to delete a relationship in neo4j 1.6 using cypher, but getting error.

```
start n = node(1) match n-[r:KNOWS]-m delete r;
```

I want to delete all relationships of type KNOWS , but I am getting the error -

```
==> SyntaxException: expected return clause
==> "start n = node(1) match n-[r:KNOWS]-m delete r;  "
```

Even if I give

```
start n = node(1) match n-[r:KNOWS]-m delete r return count(r);
```

it doesnt work.

Note : Above issue is not seen on neo4j 1.8, but I have to somehow run the query on neo4j 1.6.

Comment: you can use your `neo4j-shell` with `traverse` and `rmrel` commands or the javascript `eval`. You *should* be also able to run a 1.8 shell against 1.6 as the store-format hasn't changed. But be sure to make a backup before!!

Comment: thanks Michael for the reply, I am your fan! eval is good for small changes in nodes but for a huge number of nodes(million) it takes hours to do so and somehow not reliable (eg. getRelationships() works on one system and not on another system with same version of neo4j).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do this via Cypher at least using 1.6

Mutating Cypher is available from 1.8.
You might have to use the API to delete.

Comment: API takes long time to delete the relationships/nodes.I suppose it involves REST calls for each crudx operation.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time on the best way to do this for a large number of nodes, moving the data folder from a neo4j 1.6 instance to neo4j 1.8 instance and running cypher queries there is the fastest way and outperforms running javascript on neo4j-shell / calling the REST api.